# Data structure having two keys in java

Tags: java, data-structures, key, concurrenthashmap

I have a following scenario.

1) Module A sends parameter to Modele B, and then Module B makes a request to Module C to provide values for that parameter. (There can be many requesters i.e. Module A1,A2 etc. as Module A). The Module C then sends the parameter value to Module B, and then Module B sends the values back to the Module A. Thus Module B is a middleware.

2) Here Module B gives a unique **intKey** to each requesters (to Module A1,A2 etc.) And Module C gives unique **StringKey** per requester to the Module B.

3) Module B is responsible to give correct values to correct requester. That means it has to map StringKey to intKey. Currently it does so by creating two concurrent hashmaps.
i) **intKey,StringKey** and ii) **StringKey,intKey**

The problem now is that the Module B has to all the time iterate over the Maps to find the correct requester (Module A).

I was wondering if I can have a data structure where I have two keys and if I give any one say Key1 then I can retrieve its corresponding key2 and also the other way. Is there any way I can get rid of these two concurrent Hashmaps ? I would highly appreciate any help regarding this.

Answer (score 1):

Essentially no - you cannot get away from using two maps, concurrent or otherwise, because you are working with two different types of key (unless you decide to use `Map<Object,Object>` which would be criminal).

But - you can hide the complexity:

```
public interface BiMap<P, Q> {

    public Q putQ(P key, Q value);

    public Q getQ(P key);

    public P putP(P key, Q value);

    public P getP(Q key);
}
```

Now wrap your two maps in one of those and things **look** tidier, they just aren't tidy inside.

This should work:

```
public class BiMap<P, Q> {

    final Map<P, Q> pq;
    final Map<Q, P> qp;

    public BiMap(MapFactory maker) {
        pq = maker.<P, Q>make();
        qp = maker.<Q, P>make();
    }

    public BiMap() {
        // Default to ConcurrentHashMap
        this(MapFactory.ConcurrentHashMap);
    }

    public Q putQ(P key, Q value) {
        return pq.put(key, value);
    }

    public Q getQ(P key) {
        return pq.get(key);
    }

    public P putP(Q key, P value) {
        return qp.put(key, value);
    }

    public P getP(Q key) {
        return qp.get(key);
    }

    // Puts both at once.
    public synchronized void put(P p, Q q) {
        putQ(p, q);
        putP(q, p);
    }

    public enum MapFactory {

        ConcurrentHashMap {

                    @Override
                    <P, Q> Map<P, Q> make() {
                        return new java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap<P,Q>();
                    }

                };

        abstract <P, Q> Map<P, Q> make();
    }
}
```